Manga (possibly a manhua) where the main character travels up a tower. He meets a bunny every time he goes up a stage
The main character(male) is traveling up a tower.
Every time he goes up a stage in the tower he meets a bunny eared girl, possibly the administrator for the tower(?) or some sort of helper(?). I think he also sometimes bribes her with cakes or carrots for info and tips.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Basically the only thing you remember is that the tower admin is a bunny?  Do you mean an actual rabbit or a bunny-eared girl?

Solo Farming in the Tower? It's got a tower and no shortage of rabbits. He doesn't really go up or down the levels though.

female bunny eared girl, quite some time ago i dont remember where or when. maybe 1 or 2 years ago

Sounds like The Tutorial is too Tough
With KiriKiri being the bunny-girl.

Lee Hojae had given up his life as a pro gamer, until one day he received a mysterious message: “Congratulations! You’ve been invited to the Tutorial World.” Intrigued, he enters the game and confidently chooses “hell” difficulty, but soon learns that he is trapped there. With a mere 0.01% survival rate, Hojae must somehow overcome the game’s agonizing challenges to figure out the real reason he was invited. This tutorial may be tough, but its secrets are what’s truly hellacious.

Lee Ho Jae meets a girl with bunny ears:

He bribes her with cake:


I don't think I'm enough of an expert to vote on this matter, but so far this is the first answer that contains a "bunny-eared girl" rather than a male-presenting bunny or a non-gendered bunny.

That's because the question has been updated to include that after most of the answers were posted. It was just a bunny.

This could well be Second Life Ranker (or Ranker Who Lives a Second Time)

Yeonwoo’s brother disappeared years ago, and he’s devastated to learn of his death. As he copes with his loss, he’s given a pocket watch and learns there’s more to his brother’s death: he was betrayed while competing in the Tower of the Sun God. Now it’s Yeonwoo’s turn to use the knowledge his brother left behind. Can Yeonwoo (call sign: Cain) navigate that world and gain enough power and experience to reach the top of the tower, defeating his brother’s enemies and all those who stand in his way?


A recurring character who shows up at various level completions is Laplace, one of the 12 floor guardians denoted the Zodiac. Laplace is a rabbit and takes notice of the MC from an early floor then periodically interacts with the MC as he clears various areas within the tower.


Oh wow, this thing looks like direct ripoff of Tower of God :D

If anything, it's the other way around. The light novel for this was translated before Tower of god was even released. Plus the quality of this story is much better IMHO.

Maybe I'm blind, but all the info I can find points to the novel coming out in 2017? ToG is much older than that.

Could it be Tower of God?

Fame. Glory. Power. Anything in your wildest dreams is possible when
you reach the top of the Tower of God. Those lucky enough to be chosen
by the tower ascend each floor in hopes of fulfilling their dreams,
but to succeed, they must complete dangerous and deadly tests along
the way. But there are others who can enter the structure on their own
free will; these “irregulars” are feared by many and are said to leave
chaos and change in their wake. Twenty-Fifth Baam is one such
irregular who begins to climb the Tower of God in hopes of reuniting
with his childhood friend Rachel, but as he soon discovers, this
perilous path will put him in the crosshairs of fierce competitors,
untrustworthy rivals and terrifying monsters, and he might not make it
out alive…

The main character climbs the tower and takes tests in each floor. The manga has a bunny-like administrator guy called Headon.


Is this Dungeon Reset...?

Dawoon's ordinary life is turned upside down when he is summoned into the Dungeon, where he must play a deadly game, outlasting dangerous monsters and life-threatening traps. To make matters worse, he's only a mere crafter with zero combat abilities. But after Dawoon falls into a trap and survives after a glitched reset, he's gained random but oddly helpful skills. He'll need to get creative to clear the game and return home, with a bloodthirsty assistant and an adorable ground squirrel along for the ride. Now that the rules no longer apply to him, what possibilities await in the tunnels below?



I see a bunny on the cover photo. Does it appear each time he goes up a level?

@Valorum: Not really, although he becomes a fairly frequent companion when he realizes that Dawoon has glitched how things are supposed to work.
